# Waiting for a background worker to finish without blocking UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have an application that needs to wait for a background worker to finish before moving on. The background worker is in charge of writing some values to a USB device that initializes it. The problem with the background worker is that my main program can try to access the USB device before the background worker is finished initializing.

While the background worker is working, the UI thread shows a "please wait" with an animated progress bar. The progress bar does **not** reflect how far along the background worker is, it merely 'spins'.

I have read a few questions that say not to use a background worker, because I really don't want it to run asynchronously (which is true), however, without using a background worker, my "please wait" dialog blocks and doesn't show the animation. I have also read a lot that tells me to only use one UI thread, which then supports the use of a background worker.

I have also tried to put the "please wait" spinner in a separate thread, but that introduces complexities and strange race conditions where the "please wait" windows tries to close before it has opened.

What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: What is the script that you are using to start your application?

Comment: What you did seems the way to go for me. What is wrong with asynchronous work? We are going into an asynchronous world of computing. Don't be afraid of it (and use descent libraries)

Comment: @SteveB I ended up not changing anything except causing the script to wait to run. I don't mind the asynchronous calls, but finding and fixing race conditions can be a bit challenging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what `BackgroundWorker` is designed for. Although there are other ways to accomplish this, what you're doing is just fine.

Comment: Then I must be doing something wrong... One case where it fails: The very last thing the background work is set a value on the USB device to '1', yet I can read from the USB device before the background worker has finished and read '0'

Comment: @Azkar what are you doing to prevent the UI from reading from the device while busy? You may need to post some code.

Comment: If you see above, the UI does get disabled, but if I load the application with a script, the script begins executing before the background worker is finished.

Comment: @Azkar Then you'll need something to tell the script not to proceed. Without code, it's difficult to provide more detail. In short, look at the BackgroundWorker to determine when it's done, then allow the script to continue.

Comment: Ah. It seems the problem is not the background worker and UI thread, but the problem with the script. Not every script will need a usb device connected/initialized, so it would make sense that the script would have to know to wait for the device to become initialized.

Comment: Answered because I ended up not changing anything other than making the script wait

Answer (score 3):

> I have read a few questions that say not to use a background worker

Don't really know why people have suggested *not* to use this as it's exactly what it was designed for. Ideally what you would want to do is show a **modal** dialog with the spinner and an option to cancel, that way the user is blocked by the UI from interrupting the write process on the USB.

Even simply disabling the buttons during the write process could suffice.

Comment: The buttons do go enabled. The problem arises when I start the application with a script input. The script begins running before the background worker has initialized the device.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two separate issues you are trying to resolve.

The first one is how to prevent the Main (UI) thread accessing an uninitialized USB device. The other one is handling the "Please Wait" spinner dialog.

My suggestions are:

1. Keep the `BackgroundWworker` handling the USB device initialization.
2. Add a boolean field to your class, to flag when the USB device completed initialization
   e.g.

   `private volatile bool _usbDeviceInited = false;`
3. The last thing your background worker will do, is set this flag to `true`.
4. Centralize access to the USB device by means of a property. The getter method can inspect the boolean field and return a null value (or raise an exception if you prefer) if USB initialization has not completed.
5. Modify your code to check if null is being returned (or handle the exception, if you chose to raise one) by the property giving access to the USB device, meaning it is not ready for use.   You can handle this condition to alert the user that the USB device is not ready.

The previous steps are one way to solve your first issue. 
Now, for the spinner.

I suggest suscribing to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event of your `BackgroundWorker`. If your `BackgroundWorker` was created from the main UI thread, the event will fire in the main UIThread (meaning it's safe to interact with the user interface elements).  From there you can simply close and dispose your "Please Wait" dialog. You should also check the `AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Error` property to ensure no error condition was raised from the BackgroundWorker thread while initializing the USB device.

**EDIT:**
I have just read that your app may run a script that immediately tries to access the USB device.  Using the pattern I suggested, you may "poll" the property before running the script until it returns a value different than null like this:

```
bool timedOut = false;
DateTime timeout = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(timeoutSeconds);
while ( MyClass.MyUsbDevice == null ) {
   if( DateTime.Now > timeout ) {
      timedOut = true;
      break;
   }
   Thread.Sleep(0); // Avoid pegging the CPU, yield it to other processes
}

if( !timedOut ) {
   // run the script
} else {
   // Handle timeout
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: On second thought, I think my suggestion will freeze the UI thread, even if you are yielding it to other processes.

Comment: If under WinForms, you may substitute `Thread.Sleep(0)` for `Application.DoEvents()` to prevent the UI thread freeze. This is usually seen as a "code smell". If you're under WPF (or don't like using Application.DoEvents, which is really a kludge), then I would suggest changing the `while` loop for a Timer event that keeps firing regularly until the USB property is ready or a timeout occurs.  This will avoid the code freeze and allow the application to process the event pump.

Comment: On third thought, @ispiro solution is better, spawn the script as part of the RunWorkerCompleted event handler  =)

Answer (score 2):

Put the part that has to be executed after the `BackgroundWorker` has finished (-the script) in the `BackgroundWorker`'s `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.